# A circle is divided into $5$ parts as shown in the diagram and parts are colored either red or green. Find which area is bigger.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, area

In the given diagram, there are $5$ points $A, B, C, D$ and $E$ on the circumference of the circle such that $\angle ABC = \angle BCD = \angle CDE = 45^{\circ}$ and $O$ is the center of the circle.

Sectors made by $AB$ and $DE$, and area of the circle between $BC$ and $CD$ are highlighted in green. Area of the circle between $AB$ and $BC$, and between $CD$ and $DE$ are highlighted in red.

Which area is bigger, the area highlighted in red or the area highlighted in green?

[image]

This was sent to me by someone. While I solved the problem (given below), the sender said that the source solution arrived at the conclusion that points $A$, $O$ and $E$ are collinear and $OC \perp AE$, so $\displaystyle \angle OCB = \angle OCD = \frac{45^{\circ}}{2}=22.5^{\circ}$. While I agree with points being collinear and $OC \perp AE$ but that cannot obviously be the reason for the angles being equal. In fact the solution does not depend on them being equal as we can see. I am seeking help in establishing $\angle OCB = \angle OCD$ if that is indeed true, which I cannot see how one can conclude based on what is given.

**My solution:** Say, $\angle OCB = \theta$. Then, $\angle ACB = \angle OCD = (45^{\circ}-\theta)$ and $\angle DCE = \theta$.

Segment $AB= \displaystyle r^2 \left[\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta-\sin(45^{\circ}-\theta)\cos(45^{\circ}-\theta)\right]$
Segment $DE= \displaystyle r^2 \left[\theta-\sin \theta \cos \theta\right]$

$\triangle OBC = r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$
$\triangle ODC = r^2 \sin(45^{\circ}-\theta)\cos(45^{\circ}-\theta)$

Section $BOD = \dfrac{\pi}{4} r^2$

Adding all of the above, total area in green $= \dfrac{\pi}{2} r^2$. So the red area has to be the same too.

**In addition to my question on $OC$ being bisector of $\angle BCD$, let me also know if any of you have a simpler solution.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reflect the area $ABC$ such that $A\to A'$ and $B\leftrightarrow C$, and similarly reflect the area $CDE$ such that $C\leftrightarrow D$ and $E\to E'$. All sectional parts then have a vertex at $C$. We now have a limiting case of the [Pizza Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem) ("limiting" because the center of the cutter is on the circumference). This theorem says that the white and the grey parts in the figure have the same area.

[image]

Comment: thank you. While I was looking for a solution like this, that would not require calculation, I am not confident of the limiting case of pizza theorem. I can see it works here when all three angles are $45^0$ but would it work if angles were all, say,  $30^0$?

Comment: The Pizza Theorem works with $4k$ blades at equal angles. Here we have $k=2$. With $k=3$ you obtain $30^\circ$ between the blades. – Look it up at the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: Yes I know the Pizza theorem. But this is not the regular case of Pizza theorem. I am assuming you have a point. I am trying to understand what that is.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I see what you are saying. This is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity say $r=1$.

$$Green_1 = {\pi x\over 360} - {\sin x \over 2}$$
$$Green_2={\sin (x+90) \over 2} + {\sin(180- x) \over 2} +  {\pi \over 4}$$
$$Green_3 = {\pi (90-x)\over 360} - {\sin (90- x) \over 2}$$
All the $\sin $ cancels so we have $$ Green = {\pi \over 2} = Red$$
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer by any stretch of the imagination, I just want to illustrate the dangers of drawing pictures that are too "nice" or too symmetrical. We could just as well have the following configuration, so there's clearly no bisector.
[image]

Comment: I agree. That is what I thought too. Thanks for drawing it.

Answer (score 3):

No, those angles don't have to be equal. Angle subtended by chord being half the angle at the centre gives that $AOC=COE=90^\circ$. Assume this, and let $C'$ be the point opposite $C$, so that $ACEC'$ is a square. Now if $B$ is placed anywhere on the circumference between $A$ and $C'$, the angle $ABC$ will automatically be $45^\circ$. There is a line through $C$ at $45^\circ$ to $BC$, which meets the circle between $C'$ and $E$; this is a valid position for $D$ such that all three angles are $45^\circ$. So $OCB$ can be anywhere between $0^\circ$ and $45^\circ$.